# How to change the useragent of the Opera browser?

Tags: opera, user-agent

On Windows 7, Opera doesn't get anymore updates and some sites not allowing access, asking to update the browser.

I utilized two extensions from the Chrome store that change the useragent but it'd not a foolproof method as they are hit and miss.

To permanently alter the useragent in the opera_browser.dll, I opened it with Xvi hex changer and tried to change the useragent but the useragent is in the form of arguments like %S and Chrome/%s, when I put Chrome 117, it displaces the other hex entries and many sites report useragent to be broken. Moreover, I'm having constant warnings from Google that somebody else is trying to get into my account from an unknown device.

Of course, I have no prior experience in hex editing and I'm totally doing it wrong. Can any kind soul help me edit the useragent without breaking the string format, clean and tidy.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Neither an unsupported OS nor an outdated web browser should be used. PERIOD. Both is asking for serious trouble.

Comment: https://stack.watch/product/microsoft/windows-7/

Comment: Which two extensions and why are they hit and miss ?

Comment: @harrymc can't remember which ones. They work on some websites and don't on other. I believe it's because every site has their own way of detecting useragents.